# Responsive layout out of line in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, row

If you were to look at the following website in Chrome, you would see the printers in 2 rows. Which is how it is supposed to be. But in FireFox and Internet Explorer the 4th product is aligned on the right by itself.

I have tried everything I can think of, and scoured the web. I would really welcome any help anybody can give me regarding this issue.

http://www.thewideformatgroup.co.uk/Products/general-office-use

Comment: In IE11 when I disable list-style attributes on ol and ul elements and a few other styles (on the productitem) then things get aligned properly. I have no solution for you right now but the nesting of elements is also very deep which looks unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `float: left` to `display: inline-block` on the items (`.shop-main li`, to be exact).

If you float items to do this, then the height of the items needs to be exactly the same. In this case, the items are rendered in such a fashion that the 3rd item is slightly less high than the second. That is causing the fourth item to float next to the second as well.

If a bit exaggerated, it looks like this. Notice how 3 is slightly less high, causing 4 to be stuck behind 2 as well.

[image: What is happening]

This might be caused by a weird scaling of the product image, for instance, or by any other rounding difference. Also, it might look good at first, but change as soon as a user starts zooming in or out, or messes with their font settings.

By using `inline-block`, you basically create a long text-line of items, that will wrap as soon as the line is full. It is a better approach when you want a wrapping list of items like this, because you won't at all be affected by the rounding problems I mentioned above.

Now, you might be tempted to solve this rounding issue so every block is the same size. And you might do that as well, because it might look a bit weird when the red line that appears on hover is shifted a pixel or so. But start by using inline-block, so you prevent incorrect wrapping, so even if some unpredictable rounding errors occur, they surface only in detail and won't mess up your entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the elements float or give them a relative positioning? The way i'm seeing it is that they inherit their positions from the parent div but on ie and firefox it's rendered differently.

I've had this problem and the solution for me was to make everything float left and give it margins and clearing as needed, the end-result was that it had a certain margin from the top so the elements always remained at a certain distance from the top and each other while maintaining their position

Comment: They have float: left. That is basically the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding height to the .inner class:

```
.shop-product-small .inner {
border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
height: 140px;
```

}