# How to style navigation

Tags: html, css, less

I am working on my navigation and it's currently in a list style.  How can I make it horizontal instead?

Here is the CSS code and my site is https://centrecorp.squarespace.com/

```
.main-navigation {
    .nav-font;
    float:right;
  ul {  
    padding-left: 0;

    li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color:@nav-color;

      ul {
        display: none;
      }

      &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: .5em;
      }

      &:hover > ul {
        display: inline-block;
        color:@nav-color-hover;
      }

      &.active-link > a {
         color:@nav-color-active;
      }

      &.active-folder > a {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not valid CSS code. CSS doesn't support nesting. Looks like SCSS.

Comment: The file I am working in is .less - Does that help clarify?

Comment: float: left on the li's

Comment: @user3370902 Yes that helps. I should have recognised it. SCSS uses $ for variables instead of @. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list items to be displayed next to each other, style them as `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

By default they are block, which by default occupy 100% of their parent's (inner) width, and thus are placed underneath each other.

You can also use `float: left`, but floating introduces other problems as well. For instance, if the line is too long and wraps, all items have to be exactly the same height, otherwise the page will look really messed up. In general, for a toolbar, image gallery or any such (optionally wrappable) line of items, it's generally better to use `display: inline-block` than `float: left`.

So you could change `li a` into two layers, so you can add the `display` to `li` elements:

```
li 
  /* This is added to style the list items */
  display: inline-block;
  /* This is extra: hide the discs */
  list-style: none;

  /* This is extra extra: show a `|` inbetween the items instead. */
  &:before {
    content: "|";
  }
  &:first-child:before {
    content: "";
  }

  /* From here, it's the existing style of the links inside the list items. */
  a {
      display: inline-block; /* You may no longer need this line */
      color:@nav-color;
  ....
```

Comment: I added display: inline-block; to it and it does nothing... If I remove the a in li a {} then it works, but the colors from @nav-color doesn't work..

Comment: Of course. Having just `li` styles the list element. `li a` styles the links inside the list elements. You need both. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the boilerplate CSS I find works best for these.

```
/* reset */
ul,li { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0 }
/* float */
ul li { display:block; float:left; }
/* clear floats */
ul:after {display:block; clear:both; visibility: hidden; content:"."; height:0;}
```

We can use

`li { display:inline; }` or `li { display:inline-block; }` but I find just a straight clear as shown above the least hassle when it comes to setting look and feel.

Comming soon is [box flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) - will no doubt be the way we are doing them soon

Comment: As Golez has said, li's already a 'block' element, so can skip that bit ( sorry my habit) - interesting to say this may have more styling problems than using `inline` - I find it to be the opposite. Depends on the reqs of the UX I guess.

Comment: Both will have their disadvantages, I guess. `display: inline-block` apparently has some issues when used in IE7 (but that should be abandoned by now). But not too long ago, I answered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673861/responsive-layout-out-of-line-in-ff-and-ie), which shows a perfect example of how `display: inline-block` has less issues than `float: left`. I must admit that in that case it was specifically about a sequence of elements that should be wrappable, but also if you don't need that, it's just as easy.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

```
li{display:inline;}
```